# jax confusion - what are the best practices?

Tags: python, numpy, jax

Consider the following function (stolen from `scipy`), it produces a random orthogonal matrix of dimension `dim`:

```
def nrvs(dim=3):
     random_state = np.random
     H = np.eye(dim)
     D = np.ones((dim,))
     for n in range(1, dim):
         x = random_state.normal(size=(dim-n+1,))
         D[n-1] = np.sign(x[0])
         x[0] -= D[n-1]*np.sqrt((x*x).sum())
         # Householder transformation                                                                                                                                          
         Hx = (np.eye(dim-n+1) - 2.*np.outer(x, x)/(x*x).sum())
         mat = np.eye(dim)
         mat[n-1:, n-1:] = Hx
         H = np.dot(H, mat)
         # Fix the last sign such that the determinant is 1                                                                                                                    
      D[-1] = (-1)**(1-(dim % 2))*D.prod()
     # Equivalent to np.dot(np.diag(D), H) but faster, apparently                                                                                                              
     H = (D*H.T).T
     return H
```

Fool that I was, I thought that one could port this into `jax` by just replacing `np` with `jnp`. This, however seems to be far from true. The first problem is that `jax` has a completely different view of random number generation, you pass a key in, and then you "split" that key. Since this function would be used to produce a random SEQUENCE of matrices, it seems that the only reasonable approach is to make this thing into a closure (as below).

A different and even more annoying problem is that something like `D[n-1] = np.sign([x[0])` does NOT work in `jax` because jax arrays are immutable, so the documentation suggests `D.at[n-1].set(np.sign[x[0]]).` However, that does not work ether, because the result is a new array which equals the desired modified `D.` So, the correct syntax appears to be:
`D=D.at[n-1].set(np.sign[x[0]]).` Is this really so? It looks really gross. The final result was this:

```
def rvs(dim=3):
   key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)
   def rvs_aux():
       nonlocal key
       H = jnp.eye(dim)
       D = jnp.ones((dim,))
       for n in range(1, dim):
           key, subkey = jax.random.split(key)
           x = jax.random.normal(subkey, shape=(dim-n+1,))
           D=(D.at[n-1].set(jnp.sign(x[0])))                                                                                                                                        
           x=(x.at[0].set(x[0] - D[n-1]*jnp.sqrt((x*x).sum())))
           # Householder transformation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
           Hx = (jnp.eye(dim-n+1) - 2.*jnp.outer(x, x)/(x*x).sum())
           mat = jnp.eye(dim)                                                                                                                                                                  
           mat=(mat.at[n-1:, n-1:].set(Hx))
           H = jnp.dot(H, mat)
      # Fix the last sign such that the determinant is 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      D=(D.at[-1].set((-1)**(1-(dim % 2))*D.prod()))
      # Equivalent to np.dot(np.diag(D), H) but faster, apparently                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      H = (D*H.T).T
      return H
  return jax.jit(rvs_aux)
```

Is this how such things should be written? Any words of wisdom appreciated.

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Answer (score 4):

> Fool that I was, I thought that one could port this into jax by just replacing `np` with `jnp`. This, however seems to be far from true.

Yeah, random numbers and in-place updates are two of the main incompatibilities mentioned in the [Sharp Bits](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html) docs.

> So, the correct syntax appears to be: `D = D.at[n-1].set(np.sign[x[0]])`. Is this really so?

Yes, this is the best method to use instead of in-place updates. As for its grossness, I suppose it's a matter of preference. I really like JAX's functional update syntax, but I understand if you disagree.

Looking at your final function, your approach is close to what I'd call "best practice", but I'd simplify it a bit by wrapping the main function in `jit` with `static_argnames`, and also by making the random key an explicit argument:

```python
from functools import partial
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['dim'])
def rvs(key, dim=3):
    H = jnp.eye(dim)
    D = jnp.ones((dim,))
    for n in range(1, dim):
        key, subkey = jax.random.split(key)
        x = jax.random.normal(subkey, shape=(dim-n+1,))
        D = D.at[n-1].set(jnp.sign(x[0]))
        x = x.at[0].set(x[0] - D[n-1]*jnp.sqrt((x*x).sum()))
        # Householder transformation
        Hx = (jnp.eye(dim-n+1) - 2.*jnp.outer(x, x)/(x*x).sum())
        mat = jnp.eye(dim).at[n-1:, n-1:].set(Hx)
        H = jnp.dot(H, mat)
    # Fix the last sign such that the determinant is 1
    D = D.at[-1].set((-1)**(1-(dim % 2))*D.prod())
    # Equivalent to np.dot(np.diag(D), H) but faster, apparently
    H = (D*H.T).T
    return H

key=jax.random.PRNGKey(42)
rvs(key, 3)
```

Note that I made the random key an explicit argument to the function; you'll find that this is the pattern used for all functionality in `jax.random`. The reason is that JAX is a functional language, and so there is no global random state, and so best practice is to pass keys explicitly (see https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#random-numbers for more discussion of this).

Comment: Thanks! A question and a comment: question: what does `static_argnames` do? Comment: I had to wrap the right hand sides in parens, otherwise it was not parsing correctly :(  Finally, another question: Presumably if you one wanted to generate a sequence of random matrices, one does have to wrap the whole thing in a closure, otherwise, the user is forced to return a pair `H, key` if s/he does not want the same matrix generated every time.

Comment: Ah, I seem to understand the `static_argnames` thing.

Comment: As for syntax, the `at` seems to be superfluous. `foo[bar].set(baz)` seems fine.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean about needing parens for it to parse correctly. The code as written above executes with the most recent jax version. Regarding generating new matrices each time: because JAX is a funcitonal API, relying on side-effecting operations (like modifying a global) will generally not work as expected, particularly under JIT: this is why I suggested passing the key explicitly. And regarding the `at` being superfluous: I don't think you are correct. Withou `at`, it results in `AttributeError: 'DeviceArray' object has no attribute 'set'`.

Comment: Regarding side-effects, see https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#pure-functions

Comment: I did not mean that your syntax was incorrect `jax` but that the `jax` syntax is too verbose, in that the `at` serves no obvious purpose. As for modifying a global, I agree, and disagree. If I want to produce a list of 100 random matrices, then without the global, each of them should return the matrix and the key and then one should have a loop where the matrix is stashed away, and the key is passed to the next invocation. That seems a little painful. Is there a better way?

Comment: Actually, probably the most pythonic way of doing this (which is technically almost identical to my closure, but is cleaner, is to define an iterator, whose `__next__` method is your function (and the key is `self.key`).

Comment: If you have more questions, I'd suggest asking another question on StackOverflow or on github.  It's difficult to effectively answer multiple questions in a comment thread.

Comment: Actually the above are not quite questions (to be precise, there was a question, but it was answered by myself). Thanks!

Comment: Your answers to your own questions miss some important considerations, but there is not room to go into detail here.